# How to set a biweekly Cron job in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set a biweekly Cron job for a small Slack bot that I run at work off of App Engine. I previously had set it up in App Engine using the custom interval from the documentation to run every other week:

```
schedule: 1st,third Wednesday 10:00
```

I was waiting for the Slack bot to message today and it never came. Now the obvious solution is that I missed the 5th Wednesday of the month in my original scheduling statement. The problem here is that next week we will also get a message because it will again be the 1st Wednesday of the month. Is there a way to get the job to run as

```
schedule: every two Wednesday 10:00
```

or similar so that the job will run every two weeks?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation about [formatting the schedule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#formatting_the_schedule) you can see under the "Custom Interval" tab what syntax options you have.

Given that you can specify days up to the `31st`, I believe adding `5th` to the expression you are using would fix the issue with "fifth" Wednesday:

`schedule: 1st, 3rd, 5th Wednesday of month 10:00`

If you don't mind the week day that you receive the update, you can also just set it to run every 14 days for simplicity:

`schedule: 1, 14, 28 of month 10:00`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I don't think it quite solves running my task on a specific day every two weeks which is really what I'm looking for.